# LibGDX camera position

Tags: java, android, libgdx

(Android, Java) I used a tutorial for flappy bird using LibGDX and there is something that I just can't understand. So I have a code that always add to the camera (Ortho) x position and I wondered, if the camera x position is bigger than the width of the whole world (not the viewport) what would happen? Because im always adding to the position of the bird and the camera so what happens when the camera get to the point where the x is equal to the width of the world? Everything works fine but does it just reset the x back to 0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no defined "world width" unless you code it in. Since coordinates are floating point numbers, there will be a size beyond which rounding error will be noticeable in the game. It would look like the character is jerking forward instead of smoothly moving. This is not going to happen in a game like Flappy Bird. The distance before this occurs is too big for a player to realistically get there.